# SQL LIKE statement matching inner value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column, lets say `Col_A` with a value of `The subscriber already handles the [Price plan][%]. The subscriber cannot handle it again.` Note the wildcard character `%`. Now, I'm passing in the following input parameter: `The subscriber already handles the [Price plan][MyProduct]. The subscriber cannot handle it again.`

I need to do a `LIKE` statement that will return the same row, irrelevant of which `[Price plan][******]` I will be specifying.

I have tried the following, but no rows are found:

```
select * from LD_DATA
  where UPPER(Col_A) LIKE UPPER('The subscriber already handles the [Price plan][test]. The subscriber cannot handle it again.');
```

Note that `'The subscriber already handles the [Price plan][test]. The subscriber cannot handle it again.'` is my input parameter variable.

Any help please?

Comment: If I understood it right, just `LIKE UPPER('The subscriber already handles the [Price plan][%]. The subscriber cannot handle it again.');`

Comment: Not quite, the wildcard character will be replaced with a variable name when executed. So I can pass `* handles the [Price plan][val1]`, or `* handles the [Price plan][val2]` and the same row should be returned

Comment: So, that is a new info that is not on your question. You have a system that BEFORE send the text (as parameter) to the query will process it and replace an existent wildcard `%` by some variable value is that it? If that is true, you HAVE to change your system to not use `%` as a wildcard to replace as it is a SQL wildcard intended to do exactly what you need wich is leading you to your problem

Comment: Found the issue. I had to switch my `WHERE` conditions, so instead of `WHERE UPPER(Col_A) LIKE UPPER('The subscriber already *')`, it should read `WHERE UPPER('The subscriber already *') LIKE UPPER(Col_A)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` condition had to be switched in order to match the input parameter with the column value and not vice versa.

So, instead of `where UPPER(Col_A) LIKE UPPER('The subscriber already handles *)` it should be `where UPPER('The subscriber already handles *') LIKE UPPER(Col_A)`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question clearly

```
 select * from LD_DATA
      where UPPER(Col_A) LIKE UPPER('The subscriber already handles the %. The subscriber cannot handle it again.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [ ] to surround a special character (or range).
You don't need to escape the closing bracket.
`select * from LD_DATA
  where Col_A LIKE 'the subscriber already handles the [[]Price plan][[]%]. the subscriber cannot handle it again.';`

Comment: You can use UPPER in the same way in the question.